# Is there a way to make Amazon visually show me that a product can't be shipped to my default location?

Tags: search, amazon, location

I live in Italy but this may be a problem for many people who don't live in US.

It often happens that for some reason a product can't be sent in Italy/Europe/somewhere. I don't know why and the only way to find it out is to proceed to checkout.

I'd like it to be showed somehow before it because it's very disappointing, I'd like to see it in my search result for example!

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: -1, as I think Amazon is not a web app, I think it is a web shop, see http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/467/should-questions-that-asks-about-using-web-shops-be-allowed

Comment: @DoNotInstall : that meta question has not made a determination one way or the other.

Comment: I am also interested in this question as it seems extremely slack for them to not have this feature given that they should know which country you're from based on your ip address. Even just a "This product doesn't ship to <insert country>" warning message would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The reason for this is that even a foreigner can buy stuff as a present for someone who is livinging at a place where the items could be sent to.

And there is no way for Amazon to know where the items to ship before proceeding to checkout.

Comment: I can think of a way for Amazon to guess potential shipping problems.  They could check your default address.  They could do IP Geo-location.  They could ask you what country you plan to ship to.  ebay lets you filter your search results based on ship destination and you don't even need to log in.

Comment: then answer the question.